# Jsoup creating new elements when parsing

Tags: xml, parsing, tags, jsoup

I have the following data formatted with the help of tags (i.e. not a full compliant XML because it's missing XML declaration):

```
<TAG1>test</TAG1>
<TAG2>another<inner>tag</TAG2>
```

The above is exactly what I send to Jsoup to parse. As you see, there is a `<inner>` tag inside and this is expected. It's also expected this `<inner>` tag won't have a closure tag (in fact it's just a placeholder for something else - and I can't change this design).
The problem is that right after sending this XML to `parse` method, Jsoup is automatically creating the `</inner>` tag, therefore messing up the original content.

Is there a way to Jsoup consider only the tags that were fully opened and closed?
In this case, `TAG1` should have content `test` and `TAG2` should have content `another<inner>tag`. This is the result I need. Regular XML parsers won't work because my data is not a full XML, but in fact just data organized by tags.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without touching the code it's not possible i guess. Opened but not closed tags are not valid html.

You have to build a workaround here. Depending on the size of your input html you can write some code, that closes those tags automatically. For small parts you can use *regex* (please note: for larger Html you better use javas regex `Parser` class).

**Example:**

```
String html = "<TAG1>test</TAG1>\n"
        + "<TAG2>another<inner>tag</TAG2>";

html = html.replaceAll("(?is)<inner>", "<inner />"); // use regex to close that tags

/*
 * If you dont want / need body / head tags, you can use an XML-Parser, else do as usual.
 */ 
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

System.out.println(doc);
```

And here's the output:

```
<tag1>
 test
</tag1> 
<tag2>
 another
 <inner />tag
</tag2>
```

If even a so closed tag is problem you have to go the *regex*-way some steps further.

Comment: Thanks! However the <inner> was just an example, could be anything else. I solved this by not using Jsoup, which is sad. I'm now doing my own parsing :/

Comment: Another alternative: Download the Jsoup source code an fix this part (where not closed tags are closed) by hand. Jsoup is open source, so there are no limits! :-)